# Using Enter Key as Tab in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` in WPF.

I want to move to the NextCell when i hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and when the LastColumn is reached it should have the default <kbd>Enter</kbd> function of creating or moving to the next row.

I dont want to use <kbd>Tab</kbd>

How can i do this in WPF.

Comment: What have you tried? It sounds like it would be pretty simple to attach to the `KeyUp` event and handle an `<ENTER>` press...

Comment: dgrow.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));

Comment: i check my answer again there wasnt any problem just make these two change 1-change selection mode of datagrid to **Cell** 2-And Use This Refrence at top of window **using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives** and dont forget to set the event as got focus of datagrid view

Answer (score 0):

try this i think it work at least worked for me .

```
//datagrid gotfocus event
private void dataGrid1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;
    //here we just find the cell got focused ...
    //then we can use the cell key down or key up
    // iteratively traverse the visual tree
    while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridCell) && !(dep is DataGridColumnHeader))
    {
        dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
    }

    if (dep == null)
        return;

    if (dep is DataGridCell)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = dep as DataGridCell;
        //raise key down event of cell
        cell.IsSelected = true;
        cell.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(cell_KeyDown);
    }
}

void cell_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        cell.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        cell.IsSelected = false;
        e.Handled = true;
        cell.KeyDown -= cell_KeyDown;
    }
}
```

in this code when a cell got focus and user key down on that next cell will get focus.
Good luck hope this help you.

EDIT :

Set this function as datagrid PreviewKeyDown event.

```
private void maindg_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            //just accept enter key
            if (e.Key != Key.Enter) return;

        DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;
        //here we just find the cell got focused ...
        //then we can use the cell key down or key up
        // iteratively traverse the visual tree
        while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridCell) && !(dep is DataGridColumnHeader))
        {
            dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
        }

        if (dep == null)
            return;

        if (dep is DataGridCell)
        {
            //cancel if datagrid in edit mode
            maindg.CancelEdit();
            //get current cell
            DataGridCell cell = dep as DataGridCell;
            //deselect current cell
            cell.IsSelected = false;
            //find next right cell
            var nextCell = cell.PredictFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Right);
            //if next right cell null go for find next ro first cell
            if (nextCell == null)
            {
                DependencyObject nextRowCell;
                nextRowCell = cell.PredictFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Down);
                //if next row is null so we have no more row Return;
                if (nextRowCell == null) return;
                //we do this because we cant use FocusNavigationDirection.Next for function PredictFocus
                //so we have to find it this way
                while ((nextRowCell as DataGridCell).PredictFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Left) != null)
                    nextRowCell = (nextRowCell as DataGridCell).PredictFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Left);
                //set new cell as next cell
                nextCell = nextRowCell;
            }
            //change current cell
            maindg.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(nextCell as DataGridCell);
            //change selected cell
            (nextCell as DataGridCell).IsSelected = true;
            // start edit mode
            maindg.BeginEdit();
        }
        //handl the default action of keydown
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: @Mamad R , Its working ,I have a requirement when the next cell got focus how to make it editable also

Comment: @Mussammil Read My Last Edit. Hope help you :)

Comment: @MamadR I have tried to use your code in my sample project. I have got 2 Problems : 1) The Datagrid's Selection unit always needs to be CellOrRowHeader. 2) When I Press enter key on the cell the focus moves to the next cell. But the data I typed in the cell gets deleted.

Answer (score -1):

A much simpler implementation. The idea is to capture the keydown event and if the key is "Enter", then move to the next tab which is next cell of the grid.

```
/// <summary>
/// On Enter Key, it tabs to into next cell.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void DataGrid_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var uiElement = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter && uiElement != null)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        uiElement.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
    }
}
```